# Pythonic way to get rows AND columns in Pandas Dataframe which contains NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
      |  val1 | val2 | val3 | val4
------------------------------------
  'a' |   1   | NaN  | NaN  | NaN
  'b' |  12   |  5   | NaN  | 4
  'c' |   3   |  6   | NaN  | NaN
  'd' |   4   |  7   | 6    | NaN
  'f' |   1   |  8   | 7    | 10
```

How could I get the rows **and** columns where there is a `Nan` values. I've looking for hours but all the questions, answers and blogs are about getting all the rows **or** all the columns which contains `NaN` values.

I've made the following code:

```
row_has_NaN = df.isnull().any(axis=1)
rows_list = df[row_has_NaN].index.values  # Rows
for row in rows_list:
    print(row)
    row_series = df.loc[row]
    columns_has_NaN = row_series.isnull()
    columns_list = row_series[columns_has_NaN].index.values  # Columns by Row
    to_print = '\n\t'.join(columns_list)
    print(f"\t{to_print}")
```

So I get:

```
a
    val2
    val3
    val4
b
    val3
c
    val3
    val4
d
    val4
```

But I was wondering whether **there is a more Pythonic or cleaner way to do that**. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have `stack` after `isna`

```
s = df.isna().stack().loc[lambda x : x]
Out[75]: 
'a'  val2    True
     val3    True
     val4    True
'b'  val3    True
'c'  val3    True
     val4    True
'd'  val4    True
```

You can also add `reset_index` at the end

```
#df.isna().stack().loc[lambda x : x].reset_index()
```

Comment: What does lamda x: x do in this case?

Comment: @CanuteS chain select it is equal to s = df.isna().stack(); s=s[s]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try to iterate over its structure to get my custom format (without printing the dtype and other info)